# Do something after first third of loop is reached

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have an array with any number of items that is looped and printed on a website. After looping (about) one third of the array, I have to print an ad banner. How do I find out when one third was looped, getting only one positive result?

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $iteration => $item) {
    echo $item."<br>";

    /** @TODO correct condition needed: do this only once after the first third of the items was looped **/
    if(0 === 1) {
        echo "print ad<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a counter?

```
$totalElements = count(range('a', 'z'));
$currentCount = 0;
$adPosted = false;
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $iteration => $item) {
    //increase counter
    $currentCount++;
    echo $item."<br>";

    //check for 1/3rd condition
    if (($currentCount >= ($totalElements/3)) && (!$adPosted)) {
        echo "print ad<br>";
        $adPosted = true;
    }
}
```

wouldn't that work?

Edit based upon  u_mulder info:

Use `iteration` instead of creating an extra counter:

```
$totalElements = count(range('a', 'z'));
$adPosted = false;
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $iteration => $item) {
    echo $item."<br>";

    //check for 1/3rd condition
    if (($iteration >= ($totalElements/3)) && (!$adPosted)) {
        echo "print ad<br>";
        $adPosted = true;
    }
}
```

didn't test it but in theory it should work.

Please note `adPosted` flag, you need that so that script doesn't keep posting the ads once the 1/3rd of the array is reached.

Comment: `$iteration` stores same value as `currentCount`

Comment: then he could use `$iteration` instead of `$currentCount`

Comment: I thought there might be a mathematical solution without having to set the `$adPosted` flag, but I guess I'll take this way, so thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with a counter and test, but for fun, just chunk it into thirds:

```
$array = range('a', 'z');

foreach (array_chunk($array, count($array) / 3) as $items) {
    echo implode("<br>", $items);
    echo "<br>print ad<br>";
}
```

Comment: This wont work as it will post ad after each 1/3 of the array chunk whereas OP wants to show ad ONLY ONCE after the FIRST 1/3rd of the array, you will need to use some sort of flag along with it to restrict that condition